# default configuration with embedded keycloak and spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm working with embedded  keycloak and spring boot app 
I created a realm then I created a client with: 
`Access Type`: `confidential`
`Authorization Enabled`: `enabled` 
then I created resources with permission and policy
My problem is :
I want to export this configuration in a config file (java config or json config)  so that not every time I have to configure keycloak at the beginning when I restart my keycloak server

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

You can import/export realms using the [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html). To import use the endpoint:

```
POST <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/partialImport
```

and provide the `JSON` representation of the realm. That representation you can get via Admin Console API by click on `Realm` > `Export` > `Export`. Or using the endpoint:

```
POST <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/partial-export?exportClients=true&exportGroupsAndRoles=true
```

Alternatively, for the export/import you can use:

```
POST <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms
```

and

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>
```

respectively.

But then you will need to export/import the clients separately:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/clients
```

and

```
POST <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/clients
```

and provide the `JSON` representation of the clients.

For a practical example on how to use the Rest API have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915727/1366871). That answer is about using the API to create protocols mappers but you can easily adapt it to your use-case.