# How to do a full export (including users) with embedded keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have a Springboot application using embedded keycloak.

What I am looking for is a way to load the keycloak server from it, make changes to the configuration,  add users and to then export this new version of keycloak.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65215817/default-configuration-with-embedded-keycloak-and-spring-boot-app) got an answer on how to do a partial export but I can't find anything in the documentation of the Keycloak Admin REST API on how to do a full export.

With the standalone keycloak server I would be able to simply use the CLI and type

```
-Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/keycloak-dump.json
```

But this is the embedded version.

This is most likely trivial since I know for a fact that newly created users have to be stored somewhere.

I added a user and restarting the application doesn't remove it, so keycloak persists it somehow. But the json files I use for keycloak server and realm setup haven't been changed.

So, with no access to a CLI without a standalone server and no REST endpoint for a full export, how do I load the server, make some changes and generate a new json via export that I can simply put into my Spring App instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can make a full export with the following command (if the Springboot works with Docker containers):

```
[podman | docker] exec -it <pod_name> opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh
    -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=<interger_value> Docker recommend  an offset of 100 at least
    -Dkeycloak.migration.action=[export | import]
    -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=[singleFile | dir]
    -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=<DIR TO EXPORT TO> Use only iff .migration.provider=dir
    -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=<REALM_NAME_TO_EXPORT>
    -Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=[DIFFERENT_FILES | SKIP | REALM_FILE | SAME_FILE]
    -Dkeycloak.migration.usersPerFile=<integer_value> Use only iff .usersExportStrategy=DIFFERENT_FILES
    -Dkeycloak.migration.file=<FILE TO EXPORT TO>
```

I am creating an open source keycloak example with documentation; you can see a full guide about import/export in my [company's GitHub](https://github.com/trikorasolns/quarkus-examples/tree/main/keycloak).